# Android run time permission for external storage

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-glide

I've been learning about the new permission model for Android Marshmallow however I have some confusion about the storage permissions.

`android.permission-group.STORAGE` is a dangerous permission which we must ask the user for.

In my use case, I am just writing to my app's private directory in the external storage.

I've read that for KitKat, we do not need to request these permissions if I am just storing data related to my app only.

I can just use `Context.getExternalFilesDirs()`

But this is for API 19 / 20 
My app targets 16 so I'm assuming the above does not apply to me.

my main question is that I use the Glide library for image caching and the Android download manager to download a file which will be stored in my app's external directory so how do I handle the external storage permission for these components and do I need to if i am just using my app's private directory?

Answer (score 0):

To write data to external storage that are app-private you need to use the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission on anything below API 19. Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Since Android 4.4 (API 19) you don't need this but if your application supports lower APIs as you said, then you need the above. More on android storage options can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Do i need it if i am just writing to my app directory only? and not anywhere public like downloads or pictures etc.

Comment: @ErsenOsman I'm sorry, I edited my answer. It turns out that you need this permission only if you support APIs 18 and lower. Since you do, check my edited answer.